# convert multiple rows in single column to single record in single row informatica

Tags: rows, informatica, flat, dynamic-columns, informatica-powerexchange

How to pivot multiple rows in a single column to multiple columns in a single row separated by a comma in Informatica?

```
SOURCE:

TXN_ID
123
456
789
987
654
321

TARGET(flat_file):
TXN_ID
123,456,789,987,654,321
```

Comment: I think this [video post](https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/convert_rows_to_columns) should help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then I think with use of expression and aggregator you can achieve this.

1. Append incoming row to a experssion variable then you will have all the records 
   plus required output in the last row.
2. Push this data into the Agg and dont select any group by port (this will push forward your last row)